# Reversing order of globbed files

Tags: php

I am using the following code to include all of the files in the directory 'versions'

```
<?php
    foreach (glob("versions/*.php") as $filename)
    {
        include $filename;
    }
?>
```

This works well to show the files in the order like 1.1, 1.2, 1.2-1, 1.2-2, 1.3 and so on, but I'd like the order of the files to be reversed. Would this be possible in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (array_reverse(glob("versions/*.php")) as $filename)
```